# How can I change the style of listing captions to "Listing. #"?

Tags: listings

With the lstlistings package, is there a strait forward way of changing the label style from

```
Listing 1
```

to

```
Listing. 1
```

By the "label style" I mean the string used in the captions.

EG.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=This is a caption, label=list]
   here lieth some code
\end{lstlisting}
```

would give me:

```
listing 1: This is a caption
here lieth some code
```

However, What I need to get is (notice the punctuation after the listing):

```
listing. 1: This is a caption
here lieth some code
```

Comment: Do you mean *Listing. 1* instead of *Listing 1* (note the singular)? Yes, there is a way... but I can't see how that would make sense: a full stop is usually meant for an abbreviation, but *listing* is written in full, here.

Comment: Yes, I ment listing rather than listings. I agree, it makes little sense, however those are the formatting instructions I have been provided with and arguing with the publishers on a grammar issue would probably be foolish.

Comment: Do you use a package for references, such as `prettyref` or `cleveref`? A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would help.

Comment: When you say "label style", do you mean the string used in the captions or the string used in cross-references?

Comment: edit added to answer some of the questions.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54819/listings-caption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\def\lstlistingname{Listing.}
```

You might also want to read section "4.9 Captions" from the `listings.pdf`